# json.decode(response.body)..."Here response.body is not working..."

Tags: json, flutter, http, dart, fetchrequest

Please help me...
I just tried this code:

```
**try {
      final response = http.get(url);                       // Giving error here 
      final extractedData = json.decode(response.body);
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }**
```

Error Message
"message": "The getter 'body' isn't defined for the type 'Future'.\nTry importing the library that defines 'body', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'body'.",

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
try {
      final response = await http.get(url);   
      final extractedData = json.decode(response.body);
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
```

You get this error because `get()` returns a `Future<Response>`, meaning it is asynchronous so you need to use async/await to be able to get the `Response` object and then call `body`.

Please check the following:

https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await

https://stackoverflow.com/a/748189/7015400